# Update multiple rows with different values - THEN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am struggling with a SQL query a little bit. We have some addresses that have wrong START Dates, but the CREATE Dates are correct.

The goal is to update around 4000 records instead of going one by one. I know that I can do this based on the Person_ID but that would be very time consuming. The problem is with the Then statement since I have to select a value that is in the same row so perhaps I need to declare a value first but I am not sure how to fit that in?

```
update ADDRESS
set START_DATE = CASE
   when STATUS = 'Inactive' and START_DATE = '1900-01-01'
   then (select CREATE_DATE from ADDRESS where STATUS = 'Inactive' and START_DATE = '1900-01-01')
   else END_DATE end
where STATUS = 'Inactive' and START_DATE = '1900-01-01' and PEOPLE_ID IN (select PEOPLE_ID from ADDRESS where START_DATE = '1900-01-01' and STATUS = 'Inactive')
```

I realize that some of the lines have statements that might be redundant. PEOPLE_ID should probably somehow fit in the THEN Statement's Select Statement right?

Comment: Is your goal to just to update `start_date` to `create_date` for inactive records with wrong start date?

Comment: @Quassnoi - Yes.  There is identical filtering happening in 3 different places and trying to use PEOPLE_ID in the WHERE clause is not necessary.  Just looking for a START_DATE='1900-01-01' and a STATUS='inactive' and then doing what you have in your answer.  Even with the else you do not want to set your START_DATE to END_DATE if it's a correctly set value.

Comment: @Quassnoi yes that is exactly what I am trying to do! The query works in my test DB. Thanks so much!

Comment: @MikeS: well, technically, the @op's query would not update records where `people_id` is a null. However, given that there are 4000 records supposedly satisfying the condition, it would not work at all, as the subquery would return more than one record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE  address
SET     start_date = create_date
WHERE   status = 'inactive'
        AND start_date = '1900-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update ADDRESS
set START_DATE = CASE when STATUS = 'Inactive' and START_DATE = '1900-01-01'
                           then (select CREATE_DATE 
                                   from ADDRESS 
                                  where STATUS = 'Inactive' 
                                    and START_DATE = '1900-01-01')
                      else END_DATE 
                 end
where STATUS = 'Inactive' and START_DATE = '1900-01-01' 
  and PEOPLE_ID IN (select PEOPLE_ID 
                      from ADDRESS 
                     where START_DATE = '1900-01-01'and STATUS = 'Inactive')
```

above is your update - just formatted
this messed up on so many levels you have:

```
where STATUS = 'Inactive' and START_DATE = '1900-01-01'
```

**three** different times 
and a four time that is different but strange in itself

```
CASE when STATUS = 'Inactive' and START_DATE = '1900-01-01'
```

is always gong to be true as that is the where

this does nothing as you already have it in the where

```
and PEOPLE_ID IN (select PEOPLE_ID 
                          from ADDRESS 
                         where START_DATE = '1900-01-01'and STATUS = 'Inactive')
```

this returns mutiple values to a single update

```
then (select CREATE_DATE 
        from ADDRESS 
       where STATUS = 'Inactive' 
         and START_DATE = '1900-01-01')
```